# How can I align the custom ActionBar title always in center?

Tags: android-actionbar, title, custom-view

1. I want my ActionBar like this https://twitter.com/sayacatgirl/status/499482057181888512/photo/1

   and I want to use menu to realize the action buttons on the right.
2. So, I defined a custom layout, layout_defiedactionbar.xml.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/dab_base_black"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:padding="8dp" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/defined_up"
       android:layout_width="32dp"
       android:layout_height="32dp"
       android:background="@drawable/action_up" />

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="3"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="title"
       android:textSize="24sp" /></LinearLayout>
   ```
3. and I use menu the same time. main.xml

   ```
   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_add"
       android:icon="@drawable/action_add"
       android:orderInCategory="98"
       android:showAsAction="always"
       android:title="@string/action_add"/>
   <item
       android:icon="@drawable/action_overflow"
       android:orderInCategory="99"
       android:showAsAction="always"
       android:title="@string/action_more">
       <menu>
           <item
               android:id="@+id/action_commit"
               android:icon="@drawable/action_commit"
               android:title="@string/action_commit"/>
           <item
               android:id="@+id/action_print"
               android:icon="@drawable/action_print"
               android:title="@string/action_print"/>
           <item
               android:id="@+id/action_delete"
               android:icon="@drawable/action_delete"
               android:title="@string/action_delete"/>
       </menu>
   </item>
   ```
4. It turns out like this: https://twitter.com/sayacatgirl/status/499482637061222400

**So, How can I align the custom ActionBar title always in center ?**

Can anybody answer my question? Thanks very much!